# self-admiration or self-appreciation

Tags: vocabulary

If X believes that whatever abilities he has he gained all on his own. X merely ignores the factor that many of the abilities are by birth too and you have your abilities given to you by God. X thinks all his abilities are by his own efforts. X is unmindful of the fact that Almighty power may ever take any of his abilities back anytime. Which word is best here:

self-admiration

self-appreciation

Comment: Where are you going to place that word? Are you using that hyphenated term to describe X's behavior/belief?

Comment: @ AIQ Well  it's about belief.